# Spice code for uplim and dnlim?

Tags: spice, ltspice

Does anyone know where I can get sources for LTspice's `uplim` and `dnlim`? I'm trying to port a netlist from LTspice to ngspice. The [wiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Undocumented_LTspice) says:

```
 UpLim(x, y, z)  Function, similar to Min(x, y), but "z" defines a zone with quadratic soft limiting (note: "x" and "y" are interchangeable, but "z" must be the end argument)
 DnLim(x, y, z)  Function, similar to Max(x, y), but "z" defines a zone with quadratic soft limiting (note: "x" and "y" are interchangeable, but "z" must be the end argument)
```

Thanks.

*EDIT*
I should have mentioned that the Soft table limit project at [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/softtableimit/blog/?source=navbar) does claim to have exactly this code in the repo somewhere, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Are you looking for a premade ngspice netlist, or just advice on how to port it yourself?

Comment: Just the porting - I've already got the LTspice netlist, but I need to write the bits which are built in to LTspice (currently, just `uplim` and `dnlim`).

Comment: It's unlikely that you'll ever get them, other than some approximations or home-brew formulas, additional to the software that uses them, since LTspice is closed-source. Whatever functions you see in LTspice that are not present elsewhere are safe to be considered "off the record".